# Idiom for keeping track of state and state change in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I have an application that runs in various states, for example `state1`, `state2`, and `state3`. Certain behavior of the application will depend on the state the application is in when e.g., a button is pressed, and state in turn will change based on button presses, etc.

I am wondering if there is a standard idiom or design pattern for keeping track of state changes in JavaScript. Perhaps my wording is misleading or inaccurate, so I will give an example. I might want to check state like this:

```
function foo() {
    if (currentState === someState) {
        doSomething();
    }
}
```

But I would like to keep track of state in a way that I don't need to hardcode a string state in multiple places, i.e., I would like to avoid doing this:

```
function foo() {
    if (currentState === 'state1') {
        doSomething();
    }
}
```

The first thing that came to mind is to create an `appState` object that has a property for each possible state:

```
var appState = {
    state1: 'state1',
    state2: 'state2',
    state3: 'state3'
}
```

This way I could change the current app state like:

```
currentState = appState.state1;
```

and check state like:

```
if (currentState === appState.state1) {
    ...
}
```

However, something feels off about this solution; perhaps the repetition of property name and value.

I don't have enough experience reading or writing JavaScript to know the common patterns and best practices yet. I am wondering if the situation I have described above has a standard solution/idiom that is followed by the JavaScript community. Through researching this question, I have come across the [State design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern), and [this nice post](http://robdodson.me/take-control-of-your-app-with-the-javascript-state-patten/) on how to apply the pattern to JavaScript. I have considered going this route, and have not completely discounted it, but that strategy seems like it might be unnecessarily complex for a simple application.

Comment: so, what is the question? how to use a finite state machine?

Comment: I dont know why hardcoded strings are that bad?? You could also use numbers?

Comment: The idiom for this is "poor design"

Comment: @Jonasw this is something I have considered as well, and avoids things like typos, but it looses the clarity of strings (i.e., `currentState === 'running'` is clearer to me than e.g., `currentState === 1`. As far as hardcoded strings being bad, I think it is more that people (read: me personally) are bad at typing, and if I am checking state in multiple places and in one place check against `'staet1'` things will break even if the app is in `'state1'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As javascript is quite dynamic, theres never a best solution. Its based on you what you like much or not. I would, to run a different function on an event, do sth like this:

```
var states={
  dark:{
    alert:function(){
      alert("its night");
    },
    //more to come
   },
   bright:{
     alert:function(){
       alert("its day");
     }
   }
  }//etc
```

Just put the functions in it, that change on every state, as you dont want to be repetetive. You could set a current state:

```
var currentstate=states.dark;
```

Now you can do, somewhere in your code:

```
currentstate.alert();
```

This will also work if state is set to bright. To check wich state is the current, you can do:

```
if(currentstate==states.dark)
```

But the states object isnt that senseless then in your example.

PS:
 To improve the upper structure, you could use OOP to have substates( that behave similar to another state)

```
states.grey=Object.create(states.dark);
 states.grey.alert=function(){
   alert("its getting brighter...");
 };
```

Also this will solve your typo problem:

```
state.dak //error: cannot read property of undefined.
```